# Database structure for bug reporting database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

As a personal project to improve my knowledge of php, OOP and PDO i am going to design a bug reporting database like Atlassian Jira, fogbugz etc

I have basic understanding of database structure however i have only ever worked with a single database.

In this simplified scenario lets say we will have the following tables:

1. Users
2. bugs
3. project
4. issue type
5. priority

My first thought was i would need a new database for each company because if i mixed the bugs database with everyones bug it would affect the return of query speeds. That could lead to having lots of databases, since this is a new concept i just want to see if there is a better way to do it.

I assume i will auto generate a new database with the default populated fields for the 5 tables above under a database called something like `db_company_56` where `56` is the id of the company.

Could get a bit messy maintaining things with so many databases, i wonder is there a way to store them under a subfolder in phpadmin, from looking around i dont see an obvious way. So is the route i'm taking reasonably ok or is there a better way to do something like this?

If you have further reading material i can search on myself that would be great, i just dont really know what keywords to search for this under.

Comment: First you need to get the terminology right. You only need one *database* but several *tables*.

Comment: And do not use different tables for different companies but only the structure you listed and use proper indexing.

Comment: Quite simply all you need to do is include a `Company` table in your table structure.

Comment: Maybe you can peek into the database structure of existing software, like Mantis bug tracker.

Comment: @str "You only need one database but several tables." I would agree, but sometimes, for regulation policy, you have to keep data for various customers as separate *databases*. Being a personal project it is probably not an issue here though...

Comment: Hint: Whenever you think *"I need to dynamically create new tables and/or databases for this on the fly, otherwise it will be slow"*, **you're dead wrong**.

Comment: For what its worth, i dont believe the answers here would be based on opinion. Its clear the approach i was going to take was wrong and it seems like everyone that has commented is clear in what is the correct approach to take so this was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach any situation when setting up a database for it, but here's how I'd set it up if I were in your position.  As mentioned in the comments, you're thinking a level higher than you ought to be--unless security is a major issue and you don't want to store different company records in the same database, you should need no more than one database for all the information.

I'm assuming companies will have multiple projects.

What you'd want are, as str mentioned in the comments, multiple tables.  I would create one table for users and their respective data and one table for bugs, with columns for company, project, issue type, priority, any other information you may want (reporting user, etc.), and one more column: an id number relative to company, or more likely, project.  This can't be an AUTO_INCREMENT column but it can still be managed (I'll explain in just a moment).

You can display bugs for a single project in a company by using multiple WHERE conditions, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM 'bugtable' WHERE company = 'company_name' AND project = 'project_name' ORDER BY bugid ASC
```

This will display all results from the specified company's specified project.  When adding new bug records, it's easy to assign a new id number.  Assign a variable to a query finding the highest id, for instance:

```
SELECT 'bugid' FROM 'bugtable' WHERE company = 'company_name' AND project = 'project_name' ORDER BY bugid DESC
```

Then, increment the id by 1 and use it to submit a new bug record.  In short, all you need to store bug reports is a single table.  Hope this helps a little!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, i guess my thinking that if my database size was 100x the size it would take 100x longer even if i used where company = x. Sounds like the difference would be minimal from all the replies, if its the case that the database size is not important as long as i index and run the WHERE clause then this just simplifies things a lot?

Comment: Separating companies/projects into separate tables might give you slightly better times just because it's not running two WHEREs, but I'm guessing the difference would only be noticeable in massive databases.  It's mostly a matter of how many tables you want devoted to this in a single database.